# Linear Mixed Models with variable time points in SPSS

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, spss, repeated-measures

I am analyzing a clinical study measuring patients' symptoms and brain structure sizes over three time points. The "visits" should be at baseline, 3 months and 12 months but they vary considerably and I would prefer to run the measurement as "days from baseline". Just not sure how to set this up in SPSS. So I have set:

Symptom score as a DV and "days from baseline" as a covariate.
"days from baseline" as fixed effect.
"days from baseline" as random effect with intercept, variance component. Subject grouping by ID.

When I create a line plot of the predicted values vs days each ID has a reasonable trend but each has three growth curves that do not connect into one line. I am expecting this is wrong but unsure how to fix this. Advice?